# c++ template check type validation

Tags: c++, templates, types

for example,

```
enum tr {z, u};

template<tr T>
class test 
{
      assert(T is z or u);//how can I add assertions in this field?
};
```

in the comment how can I add code to assert the template T should only be z or u?

Comment: Did you mean to use [`std::static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) as @πάντα-ῥεῖ already pointed out:

```
enum tr {z, u, bar};

template<tr T>
class test 
{
      static_assert(T==z||T==u, "T must be z or u");
};

int main() 
{
    test<z> t_valid; 
    test<bar> t_fails; // compilation fails
    return 0;
}
```

[<kbd>live on ideone</kbd>](https://ideone.com/lcAy0v)